# DCL Lisp Bad Argument Type Error

Tags: arguments, autocad-plugin, autolisp

I'm getting this error type:

```
error: bad argument type: (or stringp symbolp): 1`
```

Does anybody know why? I think it is in the last `if`.

```
  (defun C:girth ( / dcl_id gr_ded)

  (setq NAMES '("0.032 in" "0.050 in" "0.080 in" "1/8 in" "1/4 in" "16 GA" "18 GA" "20 GA"))
  (setq dcl_id (load_dialog "girth.dcl"))

  (if (not (new_dialog "girth" dcl_id))
    (exit)
  )

  (start_list "selections")
  (mapcar 'add_list NAMES)
  (end_list)

  (action_tile
    "cancel"
    "(done_dialog) (setq userclick nil)"
  );action_tile

  (action_tile
    "accept"
    (strcat
    "(progn
        (if (or (= \"selections\" \"0.032 in\") (= \"selections\" \"20 GA\"))
            (setq gr_ded 0)
            (if (or (= \"selections\" \"0.050 in\") (= \"selections\" \"18 GA\"))
                (setq gr_ded 0.0625)
                (if (or (= \"selections\" \"0.080 in\") (= \"selections\" \"16 GA\"))
                    (setq gr_ded 0.125)
                    (if (= \"selections\" \"1/8 in\")
                        (setq gr_ded 0.1875)
                        (if (= \"selections\" \"3/16 in\")
                            (setq gr_ded 0.3125)
                            (if (= \"selections\" \"1/4 in\")
                                (setq gr_ded 0.375)
                                (setq gr_ded 1)
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )

    (alert \"Value: \" (getvar gr_ded)))"
    );strcat

  );action tile

  (start_dialog)

  (unload_dialog dcl_id)
  (princ)
)
```

**And this is the "new" code (still not working):**

`gr_ded` is now `m_deduct` and `selections` is `thk`.

```
(defun C:girth ( / dcl_id m_deduct mat_thk)

  (setq NAMES '("0.032 in" "0.050 in" "0.080 in" "1/8 in" "1/4 in" "16 GA" "18 GA" "20 GA"))
  (setq dcl_id (load_dialog "girth.dcl"))

  (if (not (new_dialog "girth" dcl_id))
    (exit)
  )

  (start_list "thk")
  (mapcar 'add_list NAMES)
  (end_list)

  (action_tile
    "cancel"
    "(done_dialog) (setq userclick nil)"
  );action_tile

  (action_tile
    "accept"
    (strcat "(progn (setq mat_thk (get_tile \"thk\"))"
      "(done_dialog) (setq UserClick T))"
    );strcat
  );action_tile

  (start_dialog)

  (unload_dialog dcl_id)

  (if (= UserClick T)
    (progn
         (cond ((or (= mat_thk "0.032 in") (= mat_thk "20 GA"))
                (setq m_deduct 0)
          )
          ((or (= mat_thk "0.050 in") (= mat_thk "18 GA"))
                (setq m_deduct 0.0625)
          )
          ((or (= mat_thk "0.080 in") (= mat_thk "16 GA"))
                (setq m_deduct 0.125)
          )
          ((= mat_thk "1/8 in")
                (setq m_deduct 0.1875)
          )
          ((= mat_thk "3/16 in")
                (setq m_deduct 0.3125)
          )
          ((= mat_thk "1/4 in")
                (setq m_deduct 0.375)
          )
          (t (setq m_deduct 1))
    );_cond

(alert (strcat "Value: " (rtos m_deduct 2 5)))
   );progn
   );if userclick

  (princ)
);defun
```

Girth.dcl

```
girth : dialog {
    label = "MyTitle";
    initial_focus = "ang1";

: boxed_radio_column {

    label = "Calc";

    : row {

    : popup_list {
            label = "Thick:";
            key = "thk";
            value = "1";
           }

    : text_part {
            label = "Option 1";
           }        
    }

    spacer;

    : row {

    : edit_box {
            label = "Angle 1:";
            edit_limit = 6;
            edit_width = 6;
            key = "ang1";
           }

    : edit_box {
            label = "Dim 1:";
            edit_limit = 7;
            edit_width = 7;
            key = "dim1";
           }

    }

    : row {

    : edit_box {
            label = "Angle 2:";
            edit_limit = 6;
            edit_width = 6;
            key = "ang2";
           }

    : edit_box {
            label = "Dim 2:";
            edit_limit = 7;
            edit_width = 7;
            key = "dim2";
           }

    }

    : row {

    : edit_box {
            label = "Angle 3:";
            edit_limit = 6;
            edit_width = 6;
            key = "ang3";
           }

    : edit_box {
            label = "Dim 3:";
            edit_limit = 7;
            edit_width = 7;
            key = "dim3";
           }

    }

    : row {

    : edit_box {
            label = "Angle 4:";
            edit_limit = 6;
            edit_width = 6;
            key = "ang4";
           }

    : edit_box {
            label = "Dim 4:";
            edit_limit = 7;
            edit_width = 7;
            key = "dim4";
           }

    }

    : row {

    : edit_box {
            label = "Angle 5:";
            edit_limit = 6;
            edit_width = 6;
            key = "ang5";
           }

    : edit_box {
            label = "Dim 5:";
            edit_limit = 7;
            edit_width = 7;
            key = "dim5";
           }

    }

    : row {

    : edit_box {
            label = "Angle 6:";
            edit_limit = 6;
            edit_width = 6;
            key = "ang6";
           }

    : edit_box {
            label = "Dim 6:";
            edit_limit = 7;
            edit_width = 7;
            key = "dim6";
           }

    }

    : row {

    : edit_box {
            label = "Angle 7:";
            edit_limit = 6;
            edit_width = 6;
            key = "ang7";
           }

    : edit_box {
            label = "Dim 7:";
            edit_limit = 7;
            edit_width = 7;
            key = "dim7";
           }

    }

    : row {
        spacer;
    }
}

: row {
    key = "det";
    : radio_button { label = "A"; value = "1"; }    
    : radio_button { label = "B"; }    
    : radio_button { label = "C"; } 
      }  

ok_cancel;

}
```

Comment: Begging your pardon, but I suspect that this shouldn't be tagged as a [`dcl`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dcl/info) question. Does it really relate to Digital Command Language?

Comment: Sorry, this DCL is for Dialog Control Language.

Comment: What is the error with the new code?

Comment: Please paste the code for girth.dcl, it will be easier...

Answer (score 0):

I think it is on the line:

```
(alert \"Value: \" (getvar gr_ded)))
```

Try to replace with:

```
(alert (strcat \"Value: \" (rtos gr_ded)))
```

Not sure about `gr_ded`. It seems to be a number but why are you calling `getvar` with it?

And you should use `cond` instead of nested if.

The `strcat` in the second argument of `action_tile` is superfluous.

Comment: You should move this code into a separate function in order to test it.

Comment: It only returns the "else" part value of 1.

Comment: `(t (setq m_deduct 1))`